# Cypress intercept only message with specific body

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm kind of new on Cypress `intercept`, but I am in need of capturing the response to a GET message, but wait for the message which has a response body with a specific value on its body.

For example, I may be receiving two responses to two GET requests, such as these two:

```
Event:                     request
cypress_runner.js:190995 Resource type:             xhr
cypress_runner.js:190995 Method:                    GET
cypress_runner.js:190995 Url:                       https://127.0.0.1/api/users/61a68c4a1d2c5258baece19c?_=1638304841558
cypress_runner.js:190995 Matched `cy.intercept()`:  {RouteMatcher: {…}, RouteHandler Type: 'Spy', RouteHandler: undefined, Request: {…}, Response: {…}, …}
cypress_runner.js:190995 Response status code:      200
cypress_runner.js:190995 Response headers:          {date: 'Tue, 30 Nov 2021 20:40:43 GMT', Content-Encoding: 'gzip', server: 'nginx', Vary: 'Accept-Encoding', access-control-allow-methods: 'PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS, PATCH', …}
cypress_runner.js:190995 Response body:             {"name": "Alice", "description": "Created by Cypress"}


Event:                     request
cypress_runner.js:190995 Resource type:             xhr
cypress_runner.js:190995 Method:                    GET
cypress_runner.js:190995 Url:                       https://127.0.0.1/api/users/61a68c4a1d2c5258baece19c?_=1638304841558
cypress_runner.js:190995 Matched `cy.intercept()`:  {RouteMatcher: {…}, RouteHandler Type: 'Spy', RouteHandler: undefined, Request: {…}, Response: {…}, …}
cypress_runner.js:190995 Response status code:      200
cypress_runner.js:190995 Response headers:          {date: 'Tue, 30 Nov 2021 20:40:43 GMT', Content-Encoding: 'gzip', server: 'nginx', Vary: 'Accept-Encoding', access-control-allow-methods: 'PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS, PATCH', …}
cypress_runner.js:190995 Response body:             {"name": "Bob", "description": "Created by Cypress"}
```

My intercept for now looks like this:

```
cy.intercept("GET", "/api/users/*").as("waitingForUpdateOnAlice")
cy.wait("@waitingForUpdateOnAlice")
```

But if the server returns the answer for Bob, then I don't have the chance of continue waiting.

Is there a way to handle this?

Mention: I do NOT have control or access to the trailing id on the url, so I do need to do this filtering only upon the response body.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, declare a function to be used recursively:

```
function doIntercept(functionToWait){
    cy.wait("@"+functionToWait).then((res)=>{
        if(res.response.body.name === 'Bob') {
            doIntercept("@"+functionToWait);
        } else {
            assert(res.response.body.name).to.be.eq('Alice');
        }
    })
}
```

then in your test section:

```
it("your test", ()=>{
    cy.intercept("GET", "/api/users/*").as("waitingForUpdateOnAlice");
    doIntercept("waitingForUpdateOnAlice");
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [alias an individual request](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Aliasing-individual-requests). This should accomplish what you'd like.

```js
cy.intercept("GET", "/api/users/*", (req) => {
  if (req.body.name.equals('Alice')) {
    req.alias = 'waitingForUpdateOnAlice'
  }
});

cy.wait('@waitingForUpdateOnAlice');
```

You might need to play around with the exact form of that `req.body.name` conditional.